# javax.faces.convert.ConverterException: could not be understood as a currency value

Tags: jsf, currency

I cannot display a number as currency.

The code I use is:

```
<h:outputText id="id_importo" value="33333,33"> 
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€" locale="it_IT"/>
</h:outputText>
```

which produces this error:

```
javax.faces.convert.ConverterException: id_importo: '33333,33' could not be understood as a currency value.
    at javax.faces.convert.NumberConverter.getAsObject(NumberConverter.java:621)
    at 
....

Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "33333,33"
    at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:344)
    at javax.faces.convert.NumberConverter.getAsObject(NumberConverter.java:614)
    ... 63 more
```

I've even  tried `<h:outputText id="id_importo" value="33333,33">` without luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to convert a **hardcoded string** to a currency number. The string value of `33333,33` is not a valid currency number. You need to prefix it with the currency symbol, exactly the one you declared in the converter. The comma can stay as that's indeed the correct decimal separator in Italian locale.

```
<h:outputText id="id_importo" value="€ 33333,33">    
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€" locale="it_IT" />
</h:outputText>
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to interpret it as a real decimal number, then you should be wrapping the value in an EL expression and use Java's own decimal separator `.`.

```
<h:outputText id="id_importo" value="#{33333.33}">    
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€" locale="it_IT" />
</h:outputText>
```

Normally, currency numbers are stored as `BigDecimal` typed bean properties not as string typed properties.

```
<h:outputText id="id_importo" value="#{bean.price}">    
    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="€" locale="it_IT" />
</h:outputText>
```

```
private BigDecimal price;
```